# Check config files for key value pair and prompt message if some values are not set

Tags: bash

I would like to read a configuration file and check all the key value pairs and in case some values are not set prompt user for those particular key value is not set.

I am trying to achieve this by sourcing in the configuration file and then checking the keys as appropriate:-

```
 if [ ! -r "${file}" ]; then
    echo "Lfile is not readable kindly verify"
  elif [ ! -r "${file1}"]; then
    echo "file1 is not readable kindly verifry"
  elif [ -z $key ];then
    echo "KEY_ is not set"
 elif.....

   .....

fi
```

however in this case the issue I am having is, it will list all the key value paris and move further in script however I want it to abort in case some values are not set and prompt that value on terminal

if I use exit in between for example:-

```
if [ ! -r "${file}" ]; then
    echo "Lfile is not readable kindly verify"
    exit
  elif [ ! -r "${file1}"]; then
   echo "file1 is not readable kindly verify"
   exit
```

it will only prompt one undefined value at a time.

So my question is how I can enable my script to check the entire key value pair and list the all keys which are not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your script like this:

```
if [ ! -r "${file}" ]; then
    echo "Lfile is not readable kindly verify"
    exit 1
elif [ ! -r "${file1}"]; then
   echo "file1 is not readable kindly verify"
   exit 1
fi

# list of all keys you want to check for
allKeys=("key1" "key2" "key3" "key4")
missing=()
for k in ${allKeys[@]}; do
    [[ -z "${!k}" ]] && missing+=($k)
done

if [[ ${#missing[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    printf "Missing keys are: %s\t" "${missing[@]}"
    echo ""
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: For all all keys part if I use keys as ("A" "B" "C")  

    when it is expanding in for loop it is expanding as:
    [[ -z A ]]
    + for k in '${allKeys[@]}'
    + [[ -z B ]]
    + for k in '${allKeys[@]}'

and thus it is not able to expand the key to value.

Comment: IT worked now, could you explain how using !  made it to expand to value of each key ?

Comment: It is due to the indirection syntax using `${!k}"` where `$k` represents the name of the variable and `${!k}"` represents value part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array

```
arr=()

key1="hi"
key2="bye"
arr+=($key1)
arr+=($key2)

echo ${arr[@]}
```